Fractional exponents in dc
Is there a way to use exponents with fractional components in dc?
Example:
user@box:~$ dc
9k

2 2 ^ p
4

2 2.5 ^ p
Runtime warning: non-zero scale in exponent
4

The man page states:
Arithmetic
...
       ^      Pops two values and exponentiates, using the first value  popped
              as the exponent and the second popped as the base.  The fraction
              part of the exponent is ignored.  The precision value  specifies
              the number of fraction digits in the result.

The fraction part of the exponent is ignored.
It seems plain, but is there a simple way around this?

No, dc doesn't do that. You'd have to implement the algorithm by hand. bc is an alternative. That was initially a wrapper around dc, and it comes with a library of math functions which you enable with the -l option.
That library includes definitions of a e() (like C's exp()) and l() (like C's ln()) functions written in bc. You could try and reimplement the algorithm there in dc (good luck with that), or use bc directly. Several shells have support for floating point exponent built in as well. Or you could use perl or awk.
$ echo 'e(2.5 * l(2))' | bc -l
5.65685424949238019507
$ ksh93 -c 'echo "$(( 2 ** 2.5 ))"'
5.6568542494923802
$ zsh -c 'echo $(( 2 ** 2.5 ))'
5.6568542494923806¹
$ perl -le 'print 2**2.5'
5.65685424949238
$ awk 'BEGIN{printf "%.15g\n", 2 ^ 2.5}'
5.65685424949238

Or if you need more precision:
$ echo 'scale = 50; a = e(2.5 * l(2)); scale = 39; a/1' | bc -l
5.656854249492380195206754896838792314278
$ perl -Mbignum -le 'print 2**2.5'
5.656854249492380195206754896838792314279
$ gawk -Mv PREC=400 'BEGIN{printf "%.40g\n", 2^2.5}'
5.656854249492380195206754896838792314279

(bc truncates rather than rounding to nearest).

¹ zsh uses double binary floating point type internally while ksh93 uses long double; zsh uses 17 digits of precision for the representation of those double as decimal numbers which guarantees a faithful representation but means the last few digits at least may not be accurate.

If you need a "power" function more often, echo '#include <math.h>\n #include <stdlib.h>\n #include <stdio.h>\n int main(int argc, char* argv[]){ if(argc != 3) return 127; return 0 > (printf("%f", pow(atof(argv[1]), atof(argv[2])))); }' > pow.c; c99 -o pow -lm pow.c; pow 2 2.5
would work, as well.

long double? For when I do theoretical astrophysics in my ksh93…
